# How to create vector of #define values?

Tags: c++, vector, undefined

I have some defines values, for example like that:

```
#define DEF_1 0x0010
#define DEF_2 1001
#define DEF_3 3702
#define DEF_4 32772
```

I want to keep those values in the vector or array, but unfortunately I don't know how they will be used in the future (as what type), so not sure it should be vector of what type? As you can see there is even one hex.

So I think I can make a `std::vector<*char>`. But then in the future everytime I need to use it I need to convert it to type I need.

Isn't there any easier way? Isn't there any universal type that allows me to use members of array as they are `#defined`?

For any help thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a typical use case for such a construct?

Comment: `define` does not have any type. Preprocessor simply reads this and pastes verbatim whatever is the value into wherever it is used later on. Compiler will worry about whether it makes sense or not. Why not use an `enum`?

Comment: I need to make the class that is interface and it needs values that are defined later. So I want to create method in that class that take as an argument vector with those defined values.

Comment: Keep it simple, `std::vector</*unsigned* /*long*/ /int>`.

Comment: @pajczur I'm not sure why do you need values defined later, but simple integer value will be the best solution in that case. You could use both `define`s (bad) and enums (better). But it will be your responsibility to prevent any clashes (if for example someone defines 2 different macros with the same value...)

Comment: All the values you list are integers.  So use an integer type, big enough to hold the largest value you may want to use.

Comment: I see that hex value is used as an argument in afx.h `ASSERT(f)` so I am not sure if I can convert it to just `int`. I am not good in all those macros.

Comment: Maybe you can use a vector of std::pair<int, int>, where one element contains the type and other the value. Later, from the type, you can decide how to use the value.

Comment: `0x0010` *is* an `int`.

Comment: Yes I know but the question is: does ASSERT() see it as an int also?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Why wouldn't it ?

Comment: @SidS: Because both this `#define` and `ASSERT` from afx.h are macro's, and the preprocessor doesn't know about C++ types such as `int`. Still, the preprocessor macro does know about hexadecimal literals, and that is probably enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no universal type that can hold anything you can define. Let me give some examples:

```
#define LESS <
```

From the English identifier, it's clear that this means a comparison function. And in a preprocessor context this can work. However, from a C++ perspective, the function name would be `operator<`, and you need to consider operator overloading.

```
#define FOO {
```

The preprocessor works on raw tokens. It's nowhere clear what C++ type you'd want for a bare `{`

The conclusion has to be that you pick one type that works for you, and then let the compiler check whether your defined macro's can be interpreted as valid expressions of that type. If not, the compiler will complain.